# Rails Backbone Marionette Template Not Reloading After Change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, marionette

I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on - I've been developing fine before but now changes to my JST template aren't updating. When I update anything in my view that's reflected in my code, but for some reason changes to my template aren't being picked up.

I've tried nuking the tmp and public/assets folder. Doing a `rake assets:clean/ rake assets:precompile`

In my development.rb file I've tried setting `config.serve_static_assets = false`

The only time it seems to take effect is when I change the route to the layout in my view (it errors appropriately). However, renaming the changed template to match the view causes it to somehow find the non-updated file.

Any idea what I need to adjust so that my template changes are reflected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason just re-typing in the exact same html in the template caused it to "take effect" and now it works.